# MFTF color console output

Tags: mftf

Please advice if there is a way to output in more pretty look MFTF execution in console. With comments, indentations, colors and other stuff.

When I executed magento tests sometimes this magic happened. How to do that?

## Upd 1.

> /var/www/magento$ vendor/bin/mftf run:test MyTestNameTest -r

[image]

Comment: How do you run the tests? With `vendor/bin/mftf`? Can you add screenshots how it looks for you and how you want it to look like? And which MFTF/Magento version do you use?

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: An what of it would you like to have colored?

Comment: I rly don't remember right now. When I contributed to magento core at github.com - all tests were colored and easier to read.